# PHP undefined offset notice

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following if condition:

```
if ( 
    $items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && 
    $submenu && 
    $items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $item->ID) {

    //something

}
```

I get the notice:

```
Undefined offset: 13
```

So I assume the 13 does not exist in the `$items` array and it can be avoided by checking with `in_array`. However I'm unsure how I can use that function in the above condition.

Comment: Is your condition in loop ?

Comment: You will want to have a look at the output of what you're testing on. What does that reveal?

Comment: Also instead of $count+1  can you use ++$count or $count++ whichever goes with you rather than that?

Comment: @PreetiMaurya In this case, $count+1 is necessary, because $count++ would actually alter the value of $count, whereas $count+1 does not (which lets him use that more than once).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ( isset($items[ $count + 1 ]) && 
    $items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && 
    $submenu && 
    $items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $item->ID) {

    //something

}
```

Comment: The idea is that, first need to check whether the items array's index is set or not before accesing that index element. So if that is set only it checks for the succeeding condtions otherwise it will return false and exit from the if condition.

Answer (score 3):

You could first check if `$items[$count + 1]` exists. Like

```
if( 
   //check first if $items[$count + 1] exists, else it breaks here
   isset($items[ $count + 1 ] )

   //now you know $item[$count + 1] exists, so you can continue
   &&
     ( 
        $items[$count + 1]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && 
        $submenu && 
        $items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $item->ID
     ) 
   ){

    //something

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a prefix test using [isset](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) method.

The call would look like that:

```
if (isset($items[ $count + 1 ])) { //do stuffs}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) docs say:

> in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack)

Where

**needle** = the searched value

**haystack** = the array

And you are not looking for the **value**, you're looking for the **key**

When you look at the bottom under **see also**, it says:

- [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) - Checks if the given key or index exists in the array

which is what you are looking for:

> array_key_exists() returns TRUE if the given key is set in the array. key can be any value possible for an array index.

Perfect! Exactly what you want!

> array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )

where

**key** = value to check

**array** = array (duh!)

```
if ( array_key_exists($count + 1, $items))
    $items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && 
    $submenu && 
    $items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $item->ID) {

    //something

}
```